# Cut off part of other shape

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shapes, crop

So I have a rounded rectangle and a parallelogram. The parallelogram is inside the rounded rectangle, but part of it is sticking out of the rounded rectangle. How do I cut off this portion of the parallelogram in Photoshop CS6?

[image: as shown below]

Answer (score 1):

If these are vector shape layers, you can set the top layer (the parallelogram) as a clipping mask.

Select the top layer and click `Layer` > `Create Clipping Mask`, or alternatively <kbd>Alt</kbd>+click between the two layers.

Here's the result:

[image: Example of Clipping Mask]

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that there's no need to resize or to move the shapes to different relative positions, then

- have the shapes in different layers as raster images
- select the exterior of the blue shape
- goto the layer of the black shape and press DEL

This is the easy way. If you want to retain the editability, the complexity builds up. Yöu need masks and smart filters. You can keep it simple and still editable, if you save the original shapes in invisible layers.

Not asked, but good to know: Working with shapes is much more flexible in Illustrator or other vector drawing programs.